# How can I hide a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a view controller which nested inside the view is a tableview.
I have the table view linked to my view controller as an outlet.
I have successfully been able to populate it with values from an array.

But now when I test if the items are nil by storing the count of these items in an Int and comparing it to 0 I can't hide it no matter what I tried.

First I tried the simple

`var tableView.hidden = true`

That didn't work so then I tried settings it's datasource to nil and then hiding it

```
tableView.dataSource = nil
tableView.hidden = true
```

Still nothing, I then tried to set it's frame to 0

```
tableView.frame.size = CGSizeZero
```

Nothing.

I have no idea how to set the tableView to hidden.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your view controller a `UITableViewController`, or a plain `UIViewController` with a table view you have added yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a UIView. Add tableView as subview.
then use tableView.hidden = true to hide it.

Comment: That's brilliant. Why I never thought of that I don't know.